# PowerBI How to add a trend curve to the graph?

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to add a trend line to graph in Power BI ?
For example like in excel

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment it is not possible. However, you can vote [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6998768-ability-to-add-trend-line-to-charts) for Microsoft to add this feature in feature releases.

Comment: Thank you, I voted. I know PBI is in rapid development so maybe this feature will be added soon.

Answer (score 1):

Now is possible to add a trend line, but it is a very basic one; in Excel you can put a polinomial trend line for example.. is very strange that Excel is much better than Power Bi in some cases..

[image]